# How to forbid direct access to website directories in browser url, but allow when website requests them internally?

Tags: php, mysql, apache, .htaccess, nginx

I have Apache+Nginx Hybrid server setup running a website with php/mysql backend.

And for security reasons, I am trying to restrict access to my website's internal folders/directories like css, Js and other included php files from direct access of users.

For example if user types https://mywebsite.com/css or https://mywebsite.com/included-php-files/ in the browser url
then it should give him 403 forbidden directory access error.

But when those directories have to be accessed via internal files like index.php in it's Ajax request or Internal inclusions then those directories should be allowed to have access.

I have tried many solutions but they are permanently blocking access even to my website internal files.

```
/css
/Js
/admin
/sitemap/sitemap files/
```

These are example of my directories inside my website, I need to hide them from direct access of users from abusing their use.

Last thing I have tried is I added an empty index.php file to each of those folders where I want to stop direct external access, this way when users try to access those folder or directories, It will show them empty page.

But I am hoping if there is some other and better way of doing so, like with nginx or apache ?

Please help me..

I will update if need more clarity about the question..

Comment: you can make use of `.htaccess` to restrict the behaviors

Comment: Yes I have tried to deny in .htaccess but it denies the access even for my website pages trying to access those directories, So i was looking for solution even if I have to change some Nginx configurations..

Comment: You cannot deny access to anything your page needs to get access to for obvious reasons. Remember the browser parses your HTML and then fetches resources like CSS and JS etc

Answer (score 8, accepted):

just use .htaccess file 
Put the following line into your .htaccess file

```
Options -Indexes
```

Comment: Thank you, I added this code to my default config file in apache server sites's folder :)