# Forbid to visitors directories access by URL and redirect to a specific page without blocking the internal access when the website needs them?

Tags: php, .htaccess, redirect, mod-rewrite, directory

I got a problem and I almost fixed it with several solutions but never entirely, there is always a problem.

I'm in a similar situation as the person in this topic: [topic](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53050720/how-to-forbid-direct-access-to-website-directories-in-browser-url-but-allow-whe) except I also have a Rewrite Rule ^([a-zA-Z0-9-_/]*)$ index.php?p=$1 in my htaccess.

Problem ? The solution described in the topic "Options -Indexes" works, but not with my rewrite rule. Of course it seems to block the access but it gives me the Chrome "Too many Redirects" Error and I want to have in this situation my 404 error page. When I try for example to access my "views" directory I got the error I described just before and it seems to switch and redirect indeed between http://localhost/website/views and http://localhost/website/views/?p=views.

I have some ErrorDocument rule but it doesn't seems to work in this case, and it seems like in the first place the rewrite rule doesnt work because It feels like it doesn't pass in my index.php where I'm composing with the $1 of the rewriten rule. There's no code in the details of the browser request, the status seems to be "failed" or "canceled".. I'm working with Wamp and Apache for now. I'm trying to find a solution, do yo have any idea ?

**EDIT:**
In My .htaccess I have:

```
Options +FollowSymlinks

RewriteEngine on

RewriteRule ^$ index.php [L]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f

RewriteRule ^([a-zA-Z0-9\-\_\/]*)$ index.php?p=$1 
ErrorDocument 404 /website/views/404.php

<files .htaccess>
order allow,deny
deny from all
</files>

Options -Indexes

DirectoryIndex disabled
```

And from a previous topic I got this in httpd-vhosts.conf :

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
  ServerName localhost
  ServerAlias localhost
  DocumentRoot "${INSTALL_DIR}/www"
  <Directory "${INSTALL_DIR}/www/">
    Options +Indexes +Includes +FollowSymLinks +MultiViews
    AllowOverride All
    Require all granted
  </Directory>
  ErrorDocument 403 /website/views/404.php
</VirtualHost>
```

In my website, with the rewrite rule, everything after /website/ in the url is considered as $1 and so requests are going through my index.php where I break down the $1 in parameters to get the proper controller and function. For example: with /website/article/read/1, $1 will be 'article/read/1' and then I break it down. All of this works perfectly.

Now I'm trying to get url access more secure AND I want to display my own error page "404.php" to all url that end with an error.
The thing is that when I try to access directories in url like "views" or "controllers", I got the error I said in my first post, and I don't know how to display my error page.
Now I have tried different things , some working more or less but I'm still waiting to find a solution. One thing I tried before and was the closer to a solution was to add "DirectorySlash off" to the .htaccess and it worked because I guess the directories were not considered as directories anymore. But I've seen that it was not secure and not a good thing to deactivate the "DirectorySlash" so I'm searching for something else now.

Comment: Please show your complete rewrite setup, and give proper examples of what you want to happen for which URLs.

Comment: I edited my post, hope it is clearer

Comment: Have you tried putting a RewriteCond before your rules, that checks what was requested did not match a physically existing directory? `RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d`

Comment: I actually did but after the rules ! Now when I put it before, it does work, I see my error page thank you ! Still the switching in the url as described in my first post is still here, how can I stop that ?

Comment: It does the switching only when there is not the "/" of the directory at the end. For example: http://localhost/mywebsite/views gives me  http://localhost/mywebsite/views/?p=views but http://localhost/mywebsite/views/ with the "/" at the end stays the same. It doesnt add anything

Comment: Do you still have DirectorySlash disabled?

Comment: No I removed the "DirectorySlash off" from the .htaccess, it is actually "on"

Comment: Then the request for `/views` should get redirected to `/views/` _externally_ first. Not sure why this should go wrong here.

Comment: When you said externally, what do you mean? I don't feel like it passes through my index.php cause vardump doesnt show me the parameters I break down, I guess you mean in the htaccess or somewhere else ? By the way, when I do /views/ I got a 403  error, but /views gives me a 301 then switches to url /views/?p=views that gives me a 403. Do I need to do something about error 301 like the 403 error but in the httpd-vhosts.conf ?

Comment: An actual external redirect (status code 301; makes your browser request a new URL, and update what shows in the address bar), vs an internal rewrite (what you have with the `index.php?p=$1` part, you want the system to _internally_ call that script with that parameter, but you don’t want that showing in the address bar.) `mod_dir` with DirectorySlash active, should do an external redirect from `/views` to `/views/` here first, if `/views` exists as a directory.

Comment: You could try and modify your rewriterule pattern, so that it explicitly does not match for URLs with a slash at the end. `^([a-zA-Z0-9\-\_\/]*[a-zA-Z0-9\-\_])$` (slash removed from the second character group.)

Comment: Actually since my last answer, I tried urls without the slash like /views with all my directories and the thing was that it did the switching only on views and controllers but not my other directories. /models became /models/ ! I did CTRL+F5 many times, but I saw that views and controllers were still coming from disk cache. I cleared the cache completely from the option of chrome and now it seems to work. Yet I have another question, when there is a index.php in a subdirectory like /views/players, the directory display the index.php and doesnt block the access to the subdir, what can I do ?

Comment: I’m guessing that your rewriterule is still catching them somehow? Can you show your current .htaccess content inside the question, please.

Comment: I tried to add RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f because /views/players/index.php is also accessible but it doesnt seems to work either. Except I have already a path for this index.php that is internally accessible by /mywebsite/players. How can I block the directory to show his index.php when typing /mywebsite/players/ and /mywebsite/players/index.php ?

My .htaccess is in my edit post I only have one in the top directory /mywebsite/

Comment: [`DirectoryIndex`](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/mod/mod_dir.html#directoryindex) defines what files Apache will look for when a directory gets requested, try and set that to `disabled`.

Comment: Ok I did it : 1) Is that safe to disable it ? 2) It works I cant access to /views/players/ anymore, it doesnt show me the index.php but my custom error page so it's good. But now the url that display my home which is /website/ shows me my custom error page too. 3) Also the path /views/players/index.php is still available as other files. What can I do, is the RewriteCond for file cant work with the directory one ?

Comment: If you need the index.php to be shown for /website/, then you either need to find a way to not have the directive apply for that folder (for example by putting a .htaccess into it, that reverses it), or use a rewriterule to explicitly rewrite that request to the script.

Comment: _“Also the path /views/players/index.php is still available as other files”_ - yes, none of the configuration so far has anything to do with preventing that. But why would that actually be necessary? So far, this sounds like you still believed in “security by obscurity”? (In case you do: You _shouldn’t_.)

Comment: ''_italic_(for example by putting a .htaccess into it, that reverses it)_italic_'' - The .htaccess is already in /website/ so it applied to this folder and subfolder such as /views/players. I think I'll try to rewrite the request then. Do you have an idea how to do that without destroying the other rewriterule that you can see in my edit post ?

Comment: Try to put one that specifically matches that request path and nothing else, before the rest. `RewriteRule ^website/$ index.php [L]` - `L` flag to prevent any further rules from being processed in the same round.

Comment: It's not that I believe in security by obscurity, it's just that if you can access at /mywebsite/views/players/index.php it gives the page with lot of php errors because it needs data  from database, that you only get if you go by /mywebsite/players. I tried to have MVC pattern. I have a controller/function called by url then call the model,take the data and put it in the page then renders to the visitor. If you go to the php page directly then you have only the page without any data etc..  which is useless

Comment: The usual way to prevent that, would be to have your scripts located above the document root to begin with, so that they can _only_ be reached via the configured routes, and no _direct_ access to the script files via HTTP is possible in the first place.

Comment: Sorry, I'm quite new to this, it feels a little complicated. I tried your RewriteRule but I'm not sure I did it right, when you say before the rest you mean I should put it just before the other RewriteRule already in my htaccess ? Because when I do that, I can access my home but everything we did before to have my custom error page when accessing /views/ doesn't work, no error page, switching again with the "?p=views"

Comment: And it is the only way to prevent that ? I mean it feels so unnatural no ? I see always that type of MVC but nothing about putting scripts before the document root. How can I do that with wamp ? And would that be possible if I put the same way if I put the website online ?

Comment: _“just before the other RewriteRule already in my htaccess ?”_ - and before the RewriteConds, that might belong to those existing rules … (As I already said, please update the question with what you currently have, trying to keep up with the changes based on a prolonged discussion is not easy.)

Comment: _“And it is the only way to prevent that ?”_ - you can probably achieve the same thing using a more complex configuration as well, but … you see how that’s going already, right? (Although that is probably also partly due to the fact that you pull one requirement after the next out of your hat here, instead of laying them all out up-front.)

Comment: I updated the .htaccess, I did not want to get a to big topic so I just updated the one that was already there, Hope it's ok like that. I did what you said before the rewriteconds too but like that I don't see any changes, the home /website/ still giving me the custom error page.


Sorry for asking you things one after the other, it's just I saw new things related to this topic during the talk. But when all this is done, it should be all

Comment: So is it `mywebsite` or `website`? If it’s not due to that, then I currently don’t know either, these things aren’t always easy to debug “remote”. You can enable rewrite logging to see what _exactly_ is going on.

Comment: It is website, my bad I add the "my" writing it here, sorry for the confusion but in my files it is website everywhere

Comment: Ok, had to leave I just came back. I solved it changing the rewriteRule to  RewriteRule ^$ index.php [L], the 'website' dir being the one containing index.php and .htaccess . Now I access to my home and got the custom error page on other directories as wanted. Last thing, the usual way you told me to not access files directly by url, is that doable under Wamp ?

Comment: Yes, you basically just set the DOCUMENT_ROOT for a virtual host to a sub-directory of the project directory. Say project directory is `xyz`, then you create `xyz/public` or something, and point the DR to that folder. Scripts that are not meant to be publicly reachable via HTTP then just go into `xyz` directly, or in a sub-folder parallel to `public`. The `index.php` _in_ the public folder then needs to go one level up `../` for all includes first.

Comment: Thanks I'm gonna do that, just 2 little questions: 1) What should I do with my .htaccess ? Put it in `public` or let it in `xyz` or even have one for each folder ? 2) Will I be able to do that if I put the website online on a shared server ?

Comment: 1. The .htaccess should be in `public`, because that’s where the requests are routed. 2. Any halfway decent hoster should allow you to do that in some way or other, but really cheap/free ones probably won’t.

Comment: I forgot to come back, I did what you say, it seems to work properly. Now my scripts are one level up to my public folder, they are not reachable by url but is there still something I should know and do about their security (with URL access or something else) or is it absolutely safe ? I'm talking of security about a direct access like URL or something I don't know about, not a user script that could be inserted due to a breach in the code. Anyway, for everything, thank you !